# cv::Mat memory allocation and releasing memory

Tags: c++, opencv

I access the row of `cv::Mat data` using `float* dataptr = data.ptr<float>(0);`
After the looping, should I release the `float* dataptr` using delete dataptr?
Thanks

Comment: NEVER EVER release the underlying data pointer manually using `delete`.

Answer (score 1):

That pointer location belongs to the Mat structure and Mat is the real owner.